# resize cover image through css in web view

Tags: android, css, webview

I am working on a reader and I have an issue with latest generation of android devices which comes with high resolution. The pictures on webViews are showing very small, while on older devices their size seemed acceptable. I cannot manipulate the content of the HTML files, I can only manipulate the webView's settings and the .css file linked to the webView.

Initially when I open the book the image shows very small, but when I manipulate the image it gets over magnified and becomes trimmed in both sides.

```
img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

I also tried:

```
 img
 {
     min-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
 }
```

This is the webView settings:

```
testWV = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview1);
testWV.setDelegate(this);

testWV.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
testWV.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
testWV.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Comment: Do you wish to set a specific size in your Java code to your webview ?

Comment: No I cannot set a specific size, for it will differ from one device to another, I just want the cover image to have same width of the webView with a proportional height.

Comment: Ok, see my answer if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, try this, you may remove the head tag if you wish, the style is the important part

```
String content = "Your Content"; // I assume your content is a string

testWV = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview1);
testWV.setDelegate(this);

testWV.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
testWV.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
testWV.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);

String head = "<head><meta name='viewport' content='target-densityDpi=device-dpi'/></head>";

String style =  "<style> " +
                "img { height:auto !important; width:100% !important; } " +
                "</style>";

testWV.loadDataWithBaseURL("", head + style + content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work, I got an over magnified omg trimmed from both sides. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: If your img is over magnified, you should reduce width from 100% to lesser value. Also If your image is trimmed on both sides, you should give it a Left and Right padding. Can you also post an image (Snapshot) so i can write a solution for your specific issue.

Comment: img { padding-left: 20px !important; padding-right:20px !important; }

Comment: place your style in `<head><style></style></head>`

Comment: It did actually work I just needed to manipulate another part of the code. Thank you.